# Flutter - Import unity model to flutter - Example

Tags: flutter, unity-game-engine, github, augmented-reality

I have followed this tutorial
https://github.com/cmrnrbs/flutter_ar

but couldn't run the app. When opening the AR app it will be going to crash. does anyone have a working example repository or solution? I downgraded the Flutter version also 3.7 to 2.2. To run the above repository.